# Unity 3D MULTIPLAYER LAN using unet not working

Tags: multiplayer, lan

I have created a properly working basic game. I want to to be MULTIPLAYER LAN. I am using UNET. I tried adding network manager and network discovery but no luck. I can play multiplayer in same pc. But cant in two different pcs. I CAN isten to the **BROADCSAST** from next pc but cant connect as a client. HELP!!

[In this ScreenShot, I have spawned two player using network manager. What i am not able to do is, not accomplish this using two different pc ie. using LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLAP9.jpg)

Comment: Help with what? You've shown nothing useful, like actual code...

Comment: There are no relevant codes to this problem as i am using default unity NETWORK MANAGER scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works fine for me - all I can suggest is try creating a new project with a couple of objects moving to make sure its not something in your own scripts that is breaking the native networking code.